# Privacy protection service (i.e. WhoisGuard) for registrars that don't support it?

Tags: domains, whois, privacy

I have a .com, .me and .info domain registered with a registrar that doesn't support WhoisGuard, and transferring to another registrar is not an option for me.

According to my registrar, I am supposed to provide real contact details in my Whois records. They don't have to be mine, but I have to be reachable through them, i.e. through a trustee such as WhoisGuard.

As far as I can see, WhoisGuard can only be implemented directly through the registrar, but mine does not support it.

Is there a similar service that I can use that lets me put their contact details and email forwarding address into my Whois details?

Comment: "that doesn't support WhoisGuard". the term "WhoisGuard" is neither a standard nor something widely known. You may wish to start by explaining what it covers exactly instead of using something that is probably more a trademark or specific business service. Besides you also have the option to tranfer your domain to a registrar that has the service you need. Because having to use a third party is certainly possible, but probably not for free, and then you have two providers to handle instead of just one.

Comment: A quick search made me discover http://domainnameproxyservice.com/. I have no knowledge/opinion on it, nor how much it fits your use case, but it seems at least on topic. Whatever you choose, remember this very important consequence: as the contact data will not be yours at the registry level, noone (besides the privacy provider you will be under contract with) can see that you are the true owner of the domain, which obviously can have nasty consequences specially in case of disputes...